# Running a script when switching Ubuntu user accounts

Tags: scripts

I have some software that is using absolute paths and is thus dependent on the user name of the account in question. I would like to run a script that is creating symbolic links in order to allow that software to run. I put these lines in the `.profile` file and the symbolic links are created immediately when logging in as a different user. However, if you simply switch the user account rather than log out of one and into another, the `.profile` file isn't run, and that is problematic. I am not sure if any scripts are ran when switching user accounts in Ubuntu, so I am looking for a suggestion as to how to handle this situation. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using parsing `loginctl` when your software starts running, instead of detecting user switch?

Comment: @DanielT No I have not, and I would probably switch things to using relative paths before I went that route. For now, I am looking for a solution outside of the program itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to start the program from a wrapper script which first creates the symlinks and then starts the actual program? In that script you will also be certain of the `$USER` and their `$HOME`.

Comment: Have the program use directories outside of the user accounts? There is really little that can be said or suggested in response to a question about "some software". Answering becomes even more difficult because this is an XY problem. You have problem X, but ask about how *you* think problem X can be solved, i.e, problem Y.